# Как собрать 1 файл в exe C# WPF или как его запротектить?

Tags: c#, wpf, компиляция, .net-6

Дело в том, что единственный способ который у меня получился (сделать из большого кол-ва файлов exe) это публикация, но тогда я не могу закинуть на него обфускатор, я уже делал так раньше и его взломали. Приложение написано на C#, WPF net6
Буду рад вашей помощи, спасибо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если человеку надо, то он взломает даже самый защищенный софт, найдет обходные пути, и так далее, особенно, если это C#, который по сути открыт. Хотите защиту - переносите важную логику на сервер, и пусть уже сервер ее выполняет, а приложение будет лишь как клиент. Так что, даже если вы решите эту задачу, то ваше приложение опять взломают, хотите вы этого или нет.

Comment: Всё равно это защитит хотябы от мамкиных хакеров, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Публикация это архивация в один файл. Это всё добро распаковывается при запуске, частично даже на диск. А обфускатор закинуть можете, у вас есть профиль релизной сборки, вот его и редактируйте, там всё есть.

Answer (score 0):

Я делал таким способом:

1. Nuget пакетом Costura.Fody собираем все в 1 exe. Вот видео, как это сделать: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CLQdCW_Bz9Y
2. После этого используем обфускатор (ну и в идеале настраиваем как post-build event).
   Вот пример:
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Eziriz.NET Reactor\dotNET_Reactor.Console.exe" -project "$(SolutionDir)Obfuscation\server.nrproj" "$(TargetDir)Secured$(TargetName).exe" -file  "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).exe"

Где в папке солюшна я создал папку Obfuscation и в нее положил сохраненный проект .Net Reactor с выделенными галочками, которые определяют степень защиты и те правила, которые можно выполнить с вашей конечной сборкой:
[image: Выделить нужные галочки и сохранить как проект]
Я выборал все и мне повезло, проект после этого был рабочий. Но часто, приходится убирать галочки, т.к. проект не пускается (чаще всего проблемы возникают между общениями подключаемых dll после обфускации).